# Calculating degree of a map $q: S^n \to S^n$ defined by taking quotient

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $q: S^n \rightarrow S^n $ be the map that quotients the lower hemisphere into the south pole  $s$ . I am asked to calculate the degree of this map.

If $D_+ $ denotes the upper hemisphere then $q : D_+ \rightarrow S^n - s$ is a homeomorphism and hence by the local degree formula the degree is $1$ or $-1$.

I tried showing this map does not send any point to it's antipode and hence it is homotopic to identity. Thus it must have degree $1$.

This is intuitively quite clear to me but I don't know how to write up a formal proof.
Any insight/corrections/help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try expressing $S^n$ as $D^n/\partial D^n$. Then your map $q$ can be described by $q(x) = [\partial D^n]$ if $||x|| \geq \frac{1}{2}$, and $q(x) = 2x$ otherwise. You should be able to write down a homotopy between this expression of $q$ and the identity map.

Comment: Thanks I got it.

Comment: I think one reason it's hard to write down something formally given your setup is because you need to specify an identification of $S^n$ with $S^n/D_-$ in order to write down an explicit expression for $q$. Once you have an explicit description for $q$ you should also be able to compute $Dq$ at the north pole (which is a regular value) and determine that its determinant is positive.

Comment: Actually I am dealing with only topological manifolds so I can't check using determinants. But thanks a lot for your helpful comment.

Comment: You write about "**the** map that quotients the lower hemisphere into the south pole", but there are many such maps. In fact, I can write down separate formulas for two such maps, one of degree $+1$ and another of degree $-1$. So your question is very unclear, unless you can add something more specific about which map you have in mind.

Comment: This prompted me to ask this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187922/mistake-in-computing-boundary-maps